# Determine if $\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{1+2^n}{3^n}$ converges or diverges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Determine if $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \dfrac{1+2^n}{3^n}$$ converges or diverges.

The tests I know so far are: **by defintion, geometric, divergence, integral**

Unfortunately none of them worked for me. Definition doesn't, this is not a geometric sum, divergence does not apply, and the integral is too complicated in this case.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1 + 2^n}{3^n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n.$$

Comment: I got to this part but how do I evaluate the first series

Comment: It's a geometric series so its equal to
$$\frac{1}{1 - \tfrac{1}{3}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

It converges since both $\sum (\frac{1}{3})^n$ and $\sum (\frac{2}{3})^n$ do.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

1. First solution: $$\frac{1+2^n}{3^n} = \frac{1}{3^n} + \frac{2^n}{3^n}$$
2. Second solution: $$\frac{1+2^n}{3^n} \le 2\cdot\frac{2^n}{3^n}$$